# How to create new string by comparing with map elements?

Tags: javascript

I want to create new string,by converting each character on single condition(appears once or multiple times in my string). Each character should be replaced either with str1 or str2,based on that if it appears once or more than once.
I tried this

```js
let word = "rostislava"
let counts = {}

let ch,index,len,count;
let newword = word;
let str1 = "q";
let str2 = ")";

for (index = 0, len = word.length; index < len; ++index) {
    ch = word.charAt(index);
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
}


console.log(counts)
```

Output:

```
{ r: 1, o: 1, s: 2, t: 1, i: 1, l: 1, a: 2, v: 1 }
```

I want this

```
qq)qq)q)q)
```

How to write function or ternary operator that would map each char to `str1` ot `str2`?

Comment: *"How to write function or ternary operator that would map each char to str1 ot str2?"* Based on what? And what does your attempt to do it look like? What specific problem are you having with it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry on my bad English,I want new string based on occurence count,once or more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After counting the occurences you loop over the string again and check for each letter the occurences in `counts` and append accordingly.

```js
let word = "rostislava"
let counts = {}

let ch,index,len,count;

let str1 = "q";
let str2 = ")";

for (index = 0, len = word.length; index < len; ++index) {
    ch = word.charAt(index);
    count = counts[ch];
    counts[ch] = count ? count + 1 : 1;
}

let newWord = "";
for (index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    if (counts[word[index]] > 1) {
        newWord += str2;
    } else {
        newWord += str1;
    }
}

console.log(newWord);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines at the end,

```
const res = word.split('').map(chr => counts[chr] == 1 ? str1 : str2 )

console.log(res.join(''))
```

Comment: Inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
let word = "rostislava"
const singleWord = [...new Set(word)];
const wordArray = word.split('');

let newWord = '';
wordArray.forEach(w => {
  if(wordArray.filter(q => q === w).length > 1){
    newWord += ')';
  } else {
    newWord += 'q'
  }
});

console.log(newWord);
```